# Clarification: Can I able to upload the screenshots taken by fastlane to s3 (or it will always give the html link to see the screenshots)

Tags: react-native, fastlane, fastlane-snapshot

Clarification: Can I able to upload the screenshots taken by fastlane to s3 (or it will always give the html link to see the screenshots)

I have some clarification.

1. If I select the 1 in the below where the screenshots will be displayed.
2. How can I upload the image to s3
3. Or for all screenshots it will give any html link
4. If [3] is yes, does it give a link for single image

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want with the screenshots. Just take them after the script finishes on /{project}/fastlane/screenshots and upload it to S3 with the ruby S3 sdk.